# How do I program this BLE location tag?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I bought one of these: 
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Smart-finder-Key-finder-Wireless-Bluetooth-Tracker-Anti-lost-alarm-Smart-Tag-Child-Bag-Pet-GPS/32806261079.html

[image]

As far as I can tell it is a BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) location tag.

I downloaded the app for it onto my iphone, and the app instantly recognised it and connected to it.  The iPhone app seems to know how far away the tag is - it has a little map of the local area and says how many feet away.  I was able to set the device name via the app, but I'm not sure if that set it locally or on the tag itself. The iPhone app also has a "find" button - when you press it, the tag beeps.

So I want to know how I can program this thing myself. I want to be able to identify it when it is nearby, connect to it and make it beep. I've searched for quite a while but not come up with much.

I'm assuming (wrongly/rightly?) that there is some general standard or approach for talking to these BLE location devices and carrying out the basic functions with them - but what is that standard - where is the documentation?

Does anyone have any idea how to program these BLE location tag devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BLE devices typically communicate using GATT, either using standard GATT services, or custom ones. The command to make it beep is probably implemented using a custom GATT service.

For finding out the distance to the beacon, typically the RSSI is used. This is a measure of the received power. It needs to be compared to the output power at the emitter. Usually beacons will put their output power in advertisement data, so it can be used without connecting to them. Here since the app is also able to send commands to the beacon, chances are it keeps a connection to it and has a custom GATT protocol to retrieve the output power.

Here is what I would suggest:

- Read up on BLE, especially advertising and GATT. For instance read [this for advertising](http://www.argenox.com/a-ble-advertising-primer/) and [this for GATT](https://epxx.co/artigos/bluetooth_gatt.html). The full BLE spec is available [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification) but should be used for reference and not introduction
- Sniff the communication between your device and your phone. You can see this [other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640581/analyzing-bluetooth-low-energy-traffic/42997239#42997239) to get started
- Replicate the communication protocol in you own app. For that you'll need to use your target platform's BLE libraries. For instance for iOS it is [CoreBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257?language=objc)